# How do I reflect on class methods in Swift?

Tags: swift, reflection, class-method

```
class Alerts { 
  class func test() { 
    print("test") 
  } 
}
```

Given this class, I'd like to get a list of its class methods, but `Mirror` only gives me its instance methods:

```
> Mirror(reflecting: Alerts.self).children.count
0
```

Comment: Frankly I don't know but did you try `Alerts.class`?

Comment: The docs says `Describes the parts---such as stored properties, collection elements, tuple elements, or the active enumeration case---that make up a particular instance.` So I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: you can not get a list of functions in swift.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Syntax error

Comment: Sorry, Was worth a try. I thought Alert.class (similar to `[Alert class]` in Obj-C) would return a reference to the class object. In Obj-C class methods are instance methods of the related class object. ... And what if you let it inherit from `NSObject`?

Comment: There is an answer in this another thread:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744863/reflection-with-swift-get-functions-name-of-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744863/reflection-with-swift-get-functions-name-of-a-class)